# Наречие "необратимо" и глагол прошедшего времени

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли сочетать наречие "необратимо" и глагол "столкнулся/столкнулись"? И вообще можно ли употреблять данное наречие с глаголами прошедшего времени? Есть ли какие-то примеры употребления "необратимо+столкнулся/столкнулись"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

**НЕОБРАТИМЫЙ**, 1. Спец. Такой, который не может развиваться в обратном направлении, двигаться вспять по уже пройденному пути. Н-ые реакции, процессы.  2. Такой, который не может повториться вновь.  Наше прошлое необратимо.

Казалось бы, слово "необратимо" - это или специальный термин,  или понятие из области философии. Тем не менее оно употребляется часто и в самых разнообразных ситуациях, в том числе при создании художественных образов, например:

"Точно всё это когда-то уже было, и он видел раньше просторную радостную местность, гнувшиеся от изредка набегавшего ветерка тяжёлые колосья... прозрачное небо с застывшими летними облаками, такое покойное и вечное, что можно было подумать, будто на этом поле **(необратимо)** **столкнулись** и перепутались времена... [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000].

В реальном тексте этого наречия нет, **но его вполне можно вставить**.

**Вот еще пример:**

Воспитанный в деревне на романтических идеалах,  он **необратимо столкнулся** с реалиями жизни большого города и изменился  в результате как  внешне, так и духовно (обыкновенная история).

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за уделенное внимание моему вопросу.

Comment: _**Вот еще пример:

Воспитанный в деревне на романтических идеалах, он необратимо столкнулся...**_ === Хм... **Sibylla**, а откуда _пример-то_ Вами взят? Из какого-нибудь школьного сочинения?

Comment: Ну да,  это мое собственное творчество на школьную тему. А что, не очень? Здесь как раз говорится о "необратимости последствий столкновения", как рекомендует .Alex_ander.

Comment: _**Sibylla: Ну да, это мое собственное творчество на школьную тему. А что, не очень?**_ === Да, **не очень!** Напомню вопрос Лины: _**Есть ли какие-то примеры употребления "необратимо+столкнулся/столкнулись"?**_ И если никто из грамотных (и не очень грамотных) людей до Вас так не говорил, то... это о чём-то да говорит..

Comment: slava1947, стоит ли так строго критиковать текст, явно составленный  в качестве шутки (даже подсказка есть).. А если серьезно, то были заданы два вопроса, и один из них: "можно ли употреблять данное наречие с глаголами прошедшего времени"? В прямом значении нельзя, но можно в переносном смысле: столкнулись  с необратимыми последствиями  = столкнулись необратимо, чисто авторское (образное) выражение, метонимия вроде бы.  Говорил ли кто так или нет - неизвестно, все существующие тексты не проверишь.

Answer (score 2):

"Необратимо столкнуться" нельзя, поскольку это означало бы невозможность **отмены факта** столкновения, в противоположность неким иным случаям, когда такое якобы возможно. Поскольку всякий факт столкновения "необратим" в том смысле, что его нельзя отменить, такое высказывание лишено смысла. Можно говорить только о *необратимости последствий* столкновения.